# Android Stuck with layouts and listview

Tags: android, listview, layout

just look at screen snaps directly to understand easily...

this is normal screen..!

[image]

but when i click on edittext it look like this..

[image]

for info i am using Relative layout take a look..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvcategory"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="334dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/Transpaternt_color" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:text="Recenter Map At : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_color" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:hint="@string/Address"
    android:textColorHint="@color/Hint_color" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btngo"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Go" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:text="Categories : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so how to solve this?? Any help will be greatly appreciated..thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure whats going on, but never use a static listview height. And use the layout_below and layout_above arguments on the linearlayout where your list is in.

Comment: @RolfSmit thnx for suggest..will try it

Comment: add  android:layout_below=@+id/textView2" to the linear layout which has  the list view  will work

Comment: @KMI thanks man...amazingly its works...will definitely accept your answer 5 times if Sflow allows..:):) Thanks again +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your xml with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/titlebar_layout" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvcategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="324dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/Transpaternt_color" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:text="Recenter Map At : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_color" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:hint="@string/Address"
    android:textColorHint="@color/Hint_color" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btngo"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Go" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtaddress"
    android:text="Categories : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you understood that you should not use ListView with any layout in your case.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it is use full adjust manifest

```
<activity
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"              
  android:name=".youractivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..i'll be back soon to accept answer if this works..thanks